# Calculate Weekly Metrics of a Daily Array in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, window-functions

I couldn't find a solution to this anywhere. I have a table with daily data having four columns with floating values. See picture here

[image: Example]

I want to calculate a weekly price such that the Open price is the price from the start of the week ie, date_sub(running_date, Interval 5 workday) and the High and Low are the highs and lows over those last 5 workdays. The close being the last close (so nothing to calc).

This is the calculation of the weekly price data as shown here

[image: Weekly Price Defintion]

I imagine it works something like this here for a single stock

```
SELECT
    *,
    ( SELECT max( High ) FROM dat WHERE stock = "AAPL" AND `Date` >= date_sub( Curdate( ), INTERVAL 8 DAY ) ) AS High 
FROM
    dat 
WHERE
    stock = "AAPL" 
ORDER BY
    `Date` DESC
```

but where Curdate() is actually the Date of the table 'dat' and is changing in every row. This here only adds the weekly for the current date.

As a result I want the four columns wOpen, wHigh, wLow, wCLose as shown here

[image: Result Table]

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data, as a separate text table.

Comment: Why would you place your aggregated data in the same table? Why not just create a new table for the weekly data with the columns Stock, Weeknumber, Open, High, Low, Close ?

Comment: @GMB I have updated above.  yes of course it can be just the wOpen, wHigh, wLow, wClose values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like window functions over weekly partitions :

```
select d.*,
    first_value(open) over(partition by stock, yearweek(tradeDate, 1) order by tradeDate) as wOpen,
    max(high)         over(partition by stock, yearweek(tradeDate, 1) order by tradeDate) as wHigh,
    min(low)          over(partition by stock, yearweek(tradeDate, 1) order by tradeDate) as wLow,
    last_value(close) over(partition by stock, yearweek(tradeDate, 1) order by tradeDate) as wClose
from dat d
```

The trick is to partition your data by stock and by trade *week*; `yearweek(tradeDate, 1)` gives you the year/week for the given date, based on weeks that start on Monday (as inferred from your sample data).

The rest is just windowing: the first opening and last closing values can be accessed with `first_value()` and `last_value`, and the window `min`/`max` give you the running minium and maximum.

If you want to restrict the results to a specific date range, you can just add a `where` clause to the query.

---

If you are running MySQL 5.x, where window functions are not available, one alternative uses a couple of correlated subqueries. This will probably be far less efficient if you have a lot of rows to process:

```
select d.*,
    (
        select open 
        from dat d1 
        where d1.stock = d.stock and d1.tradeDate <= d.tradeDate and d1.tradeDate >= d.tradeDate - interval weekday(d.tradeDate) day
        order by d1.tradeDate limit 1
    ) as wOpen,
    (
        select max(high)
        from dat d1 
        where d1.stock = d.stock and d1.tradeDate <= d.tradeDate and d1.tradeDate >= d.tradeDate - interval weekday(d.tradeDate) day
    ) as wHigh,
    (
        select min(low)
        from dat d1 
        where d1.stock = d.stock and d1.tradeDate <= d.tradeDate and d1.tradeDate >= d.tradeDate - interval weekday(d.tradeDate) day
    ) as wLow,
    (
        select close
        from dat d1 
        where d1.stock = d.stock and d1.tradeDate <= d.tradeDate and d1.tradeDate >= d.tradeDate - interval weekday(d.tradeDate) day
        order by d1.tradeDate desc limit 1
    ) as wClose
from dat d
```

Comment: I have an older version of mySQL it doesn't recognise 'over'  is there another way than to use over? (my version mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.42)

Comment: @AndiAna: that's probably something you should have signaled initially in your question... I updated my answer with an alternative for old MySQL versions.

Comment: very nice solution. but the values are not matching what I get in python.  for max(High) for  instance. using yours or when I replace 'd.tradeDate - interval weekday(d.tradeDate) day' by 'd1.tradeDate >= date_sub(d.tradeDate, Interval  6 day )' which is partially correct but breaks down after the 3rd day. I don't see why.

Comment: @AndiAna: why would you modify the query? Pls run it as provided first. And if you want to filter on a given date range, then you need to add a `where` clause to the *outer* query rather than in the individual subqueries.

Comment: ok I see what you did. you are always taking all days up to the last Monday using the weekday() to subtract exactly all days since Mondays -> smart. I will approve the answer. it's not exactly what I need but I think I can get it to work somehow. thanks a bunch.

Comment: @AndiAna: *you are always taking all days up to the last Monday*: yes, that’s how I understood your question, and that’s what your data shows, as far as I can tell (unfortunately since you provided your data as pictures, I can’t test the query - that’s one of the reasons why providing sample data as text is better practice).

Comment: yup I realize this now. Can you maybe add a version that uses the ‘rank’ instead of the date? Cos in my data not all weeks are 5 days due to holidays and I always want to take the same number of trading days.